# popover-placement = 'bottom-left' is placing popover on right

Tags: angularjs, popover

I am using bs-popover on hover of icon.The popover should appear on bottom-left/top-left.
I am dynamically changing popover-placement. I inspect the element, I see that it is updated accordingly. But when I hover, right class is added on popover.
How to resolve this issue?

My code:

```
$scope.getPlacement = function(data) {
    var currentCenterPoint = $("#line" + data.Id).offset().top | 0;
    var nextCenterPoint = $('#sec-list').offset().top | 0;
    var amount = ( currentCenterPoint - nextCenterPoint );
    var placement;
    if(amount > 250){
        placement =  'top-left';
        console.log("placement of note " + placement + " " + amount);
        return 'top-left';
    } else {
        placement =  'bottom-left';
        console.log("placement of note " + placement + " " + amount);
        return 'bottom-left';
    }

};
```

Inspect on icon in browser:

```
<div class="popover right" style="display:block;top:-26px;left:13px;visibility: visible;"></div>
```

is added dynamically. instead of

```
<div class="popover bottom-left" style="display:block;top:-26px;left:13px;visibility: visible;"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean on **right class is added**? Is it that a class with the name right is present when you hover or is it right as in correct? I'm confuse. If it is a class with the name right in it, why not use `removeClass()`.

Comment: @MarkVincentManjac when I hover, below gets added:
<div class="popover right" style="display:block;top:-26px;left:13px;visibility: visible;"></div>
instead of <div class="popover bottom-left" style="display:block;top:-26px;left:13px;visibility: visible;"></div>

Comment: that's weird because there is no `right` class in your javascript. Is `right` class your default placement? If not then that might be some ghost trying to fool you. JK! :P Seriously, if not then that would be totally weird since the class should `bottom-left/top-left` should be present even though right is also present like `popover right bottom-left/top-right` but in your case it seems like your code wasn't working. Try to console all the variables and result, their might be something wrong.

Comment: @MarkVincentManjac see this:
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_popover_pos&stacked=h

replace bottom to bottom-left... the result is right :(

Comment: I don't think there is a bottom-left on popover of bootstrap.  Here try this plugin [Krajee Bootstrap PopoverX](http://plugins.krajee.com/popover-x) . It has a bottom-left or top-left.